# List model in Android Room

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to save the data coming from the API to the Room database in the viewModel, but it is not saved. I trust my codes, but I guess I'm making an identification error in Footballoda. Where does he go wrong?

I did the Bild process, the data is downloaded from the internet without any errors, but as I said, there is an error in FootballDao I overlooked. I would be grateful if you could help find this error

```
    @Entity
    data class Model(
        @ColumnInfo
        var laliga: List<Laliga>? = null
    )
    
    @Entity
    data class Laliga(
        @ColumnInfo
        var ranking: Int? = null,
        @ColumnInfo
        var team_name: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo
        var coach: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo
        var market_value: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo
        var image: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo
        var next_week_opponent: NextWeekOpponent? = null,
        @ColumnInfo
        var last_week_opponent: LastWeekOpponent? = null
    ) {
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var uuid: Int = 0
    }
    
    @Entity
    data class LastWeekOpponent(
        @ColumnInfo
        var ranking: Int? = null,
        @ColumnInfo
        var hour: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo
        var date: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo
        var goal_scored: Int? = null,
        @ColumnInfo
        var conceded_goal: Int? = null
    )
    
    @Entity
    data class NextWeekOpponent(
        @ColumnInfo
        var ranking: Int? = null,
        @ColumnInfo
        var hour: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo
        var date: String? = null
    )

......
@Dao
interface FootballDao {

    //Data Access Object
    @Insert
    suspend fun insertAll(vararg footballs: List<Laliga>): List<Long>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM laliga")
    suspend fun getAllFootballs(): List<Laliga>

    //get Database item id
    @Query("SELECT * FROM laliga WHERE uuid = :footballId")
    suspend fun getFootball(footballId: Int): Laliga

    @Query("DELETE FROM laliga")
    suspend fun deleteAllFootballs()

}
```

Comment: Nice question. Hope that helps out :)

Answer (score 0):

For starters `@Insert` should not be returning anything. I suggest you change to to this.

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertAll(footballs: List<Laliga>)
```

I also suggest returning `LiveData` from `get queries` so that you can observe the same on your viewModel.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM laliga")
 suspend fun getAllFootballs(): LiveData <List<Laliga>>
```